# Python subprocess line 1420 FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified. Jupyter-Matlab notebook

Tags: python, matlab, jupyter-notebook, subprocess

I want to use Jupyter-matlab notebooks. I've downloaded Anaconda navigator and followed the steps from this web: http://jmlilly.net/jupyter-matlab Unfortunately, when I try to open a matlab notebook there is a kernel error.
I've been trying re-install anaconda, jupyter, matlab-kernel, change environment python version (2.7, 3.7, 3.8, 3.9) etc. but it doesn't work. Matlab version: R2021b and R2022a (tried both).
Full error traceback from jupyter:

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 1704, in _execute
    result = await result
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 328, in __wakeup
    future.result()
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\handlers.py", line 74, in post
    model = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 98, in create_session
    kernel_id = yield self.start_kernel_for_session(session_id, path, name, type, kernel_name)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 769, in run
    yielded = self.gen.throw(*exc_info)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\sessions\sessionmanager.py", line 110, in start_kernel_for_session
    kernel_id = yield maybe_future(
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tornado\gen.py", line 762, in run
    value = future.result()
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 176, in start_kernel
    kernel_id = await maybe_future(self.pinned_superclass.start_kernel(self, **kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 26, in wrapped
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 23, in wrapped
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 89, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\multikernelmanager.py", line 207, in _async_start_kernel
    starter = ensure_async(km.start_kernel(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 26, in wrapped
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 23, in wrapped
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 89, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 79, in wrapper
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 71, in wrapper
    out = await method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 381, in _async_start_kernel
    await ensure_async(self._launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw))
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 26, in wrapped
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\utils.py", line 23, in wrapped
    return loop.run_until_complete(future)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py", line 89, in run_until_complete
    return f.result()
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py", line 201, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 256, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\manager.py", line 301, in _async_launch_kernel
    connection_info = await self.provisioner.launch_kernel(kernel_cmd, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\provisioning\local_provisioner.py", line 204, in launch_kernel
    self.process = launch_kernel(cmd, **scrubbed_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 169, in launch_kernel
    raise ex
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\jupyter_client\launcher.py", line 157, in launch_kernel
    proc = Popen(cmd, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 951, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\lucas\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1420, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Comment: That is a Windows message. `subprocess` is trying to run an executable that Windows can't find.

Comment: @BoarGules do you know how can I discover wich executable is it?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Anaconda but my approach would be to step through in a debugger to see what is in `args`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64238517/8004017) helped me to solve it. For some reason, the matlab kernel config file points to the wrong python location.

### Solution

Edit the file `%APPDATA%\jupyter\kernels\matlab\kernel.json` so that the first argument points to the correct python executable. In my case from:

```
{"argv": ["/tmp/conda_envs/258853ccd52b78b326300497/bin/python", "-m", "matlab_kernel", ...
```

to

```
{"argv": ["C:\\Users\\YOURUSERNAME\\.conda\\envs\\ENVNAME\\python.exe", "-m", "matlab_kernel", ...
```

Or whatever is the correct python path to your environment (change YOURUSERNAME and ENVNAME). In windows you can find it using `where python`

### Extra info

For debugging and finding the `kernel.json` file, I used

```
jupyter console --kernel matlab --debug
```